# Unable to display serializers.fields on swagger docs

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rest-authemail for basic email based authentication. 
While creating swagger docs its working fine with all api which I have created using django models but django-rest-authemail module uses serializers.fields for Login Serializer i.e.

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Hence django-rest-swagger is unable to recognize these fields and failed to load into api docs.
I have attached the [picture](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4718496/6707648/ec1cb630-cd8e-11e4-8880-8932d9029740.png) for reference.